# python replace capture group value

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am trying to use python code to replace the character value 'K' with 'M' in the following code snippet, but not having much luck.

code:

```
import re

original_text = 'context PQ-4662-33-K64C-C-DDxxx-Sxxxx'
regex = re.compile(r'context\s.*\d[0-9]\-\w\w\-(K).*')
result = re.match(regex, original_text)
replace_attempt = regex.sub(r'M\1', original_text)

print(result.group(0))
print(result.group(1))
print(replace_attempt)
```

output:

```
context PQ-4662-33-K64C-C-DDxxx-Sxxxx
K
MK

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The desired output I am seeking:

```
context PQ-4662-33-M64C-C-DDxxx-Sxxxx
```

Comment: Does `original_text.replace('K', 'M')` help? If not, you are going to need to add more on why you need to replace what you need.

Comment: `re.sub('K','M',original_text)` ??

Comment: does this have to be done with regex?

Comment: Please provide more context to this question.  It's incredibly vague.  Are you attempting to replace all 'K's with 'M's?  Are you attempting to replace any character at the Nth position with 'M'?  Are you doing the previous, but only if the Nth item is a 'K'?  etc, etc.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with required groups

```
original_text = 'context PQ-4662-33-K64C-C-DDxxx-Sxxxx'
original_text=re.sub(r'(context\s.*\d[0-9]\-\w\w\-)(K)(.*)',r'\1'+'M'+r'\3',original_text)
print(original_text) #'context PQ-4662-33-M64C-C-DDxxx-Sxxxx'
```

If you simply want to replace all `K with M

```
re.sub('K','M',original_text)
```

Comment: Thank you @mad_ this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is replace `K` with `M`, then you can simply do either:

1) `re.sub('K', 'M', original_text)`

2) `original_text.replace('K', 'M')`

Both will yield:

```
context PQ-4662-33-M64C-C-DDxxx-Sxxxx
```

If your requirements are more specific, and the input strings always follow a prescribed pattern:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=context [A-Z]{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}-)[A-Z]', 'M', original_text)
```

Again yields:

```
context PQ-4662-33-M64C-C-DDxxx-Sxxxx
```

Comment: Edited my answer, thanks for catching that!